# Symfony2 How to inherit foreign keys inside a many to many join table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I have a simple structure of three tables and a `join table` `Tournament` has a `OneToMany` with `Group`. `Group` also has a `ManyToMany` with `Team`.

[image]

this is all well and simple, but as you can see in the above image there is `group_tournament_id` key "inherited"(if that's the right term) from the `Tournament` table, this to me is very helpful as i can list all teams in the tournament, without looping through all the `Group` table.

so, how do i get this field to appear in the `jointable` using symfony 2 and doctrine

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common thing. It can not be done with `ManyToMany` relation. Instead, you need to have an "join entity", `GroupTeamOwnership`.

That entity should have one group, one team id, and one tournament id.

So instead having ManyToMany, you will have:

`Group <-OneToMany-> GroupTeamOwnership <-ManyToOne-> Team`

In fact, this is so common scenario that [doctrine docs even mention it](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional):

> Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you
>   want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which
>   case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct
>   many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by
>   one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating
>   classes.

Comment: edit: yes, i tried this method, here (correct me if i'm wrong) i will have to explicitly use a loop to insert the relationship into GroupTeamOwnership, since i have teams loaded from the database using `entityType` this would make it harder to do a CRUD operation

Comment: Yes, you will have to modify your form

Comment: do you think having a composite key would make this relation happen?

Comment: No, even if it did, having an association entity there is still far more flexible in the long run.